# Python, file corruoption when converting .csv to .xlsx, without xlsxwriter.workbook module

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert a .csv file to a .xlsx file without using the xlsxwriter.workbook module. The following code changes the format however when I try to open the file, I get prompted with "file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted". Thanks

```
import os
import tkSimpleDialog
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

my_file = askopenfilename()

newname = my_file.replace('.csv', '.xlsx')
output = os.rename(my_file, newname)
```

Comment: cos: your `os` auto-check mime-types. Open is a procedure, can't rename a file if your object isn't a dump/hash.

Comment: Can you elaborate why you believe that os.rename() does anything related to *converting* file to a different format, rather than simply changing the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can convert csv file into xlsx file without using another module. I think your script only try to change the filename and do nothing to the content of the file.